# How to calculate an expression based on given information

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to solve the question: 
  If $A=(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^3+1)......(2^{2048}+1)$, what shall be the value of $(A+1)^{1/2048}$. 
I have not been able to think of anything in any direction, Tobe honest!

Comment: Are you sure that the original product is $(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^3+1)(2^4+1)\cdots$ , not $(2+1)(2^2+1)(2^4+1)(2^8+1)\cdots$?

Comment: Yes sir. That was kind of my initial doubt as well. But that is how the question is !!! Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the third term in your expression should be $2^{2^2}+1$ as hkmather802 pointed out. The general term should be $2^{2^n}+1$.

If this is the case, here is a solution.

Write $A$ as $A=(2-1)A$ and use difference square formula $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, you can get 
$$A=2^{4096}-1.$$
Thus $$(A+1)^{1/2048}=(2^{4096})^{1/2048}=2^2=4.$$

If it is your case, I have no idea.